# Java classloader - use two versions of the same library

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a Maven project. It includes 2 jars A and B, each of them requires com.zeroc.Ice jar. Problem is, jar A requires Ice 3.4.2, and jar B requires Ice 3.3.1.

Problem is, that when running project with Ice-3.4.2, some deep internal class of jar B throws NoSuchMethodError (and in fact, there is no such method in this version), and it works the same way with Ice 3.3.1, but now jar A throws NoClassDefFoundError (somewhere deep inside). Looks like there was a significant change between those versions of Ice, and 3.4.2 is not backward compatible.

Is there any way I could include both jars and "tell" which Ice version should be used for each of them (A and B)? I am looking for solution, where there is no need to play with code of jars A or B - is it possible?

**UPDATE**

It came out, that jar B contained its own version of ICE (with different namespace). After I upgraded main project with new ICE it somehow clashed, and caused the issues. I changed order of dependencies in pom.xml and it solved my issue.

But if someone faces problem I described in the first place, I think it is a good idea to check **maven shade plugin**. I am not pretty sure, but while I was looking for solution someone has pointed me in that direction. From what I heard, it allows you to use different versions of the same jar, and bind it in the way you need it (it plays with namespaces).

Comment: If you don't have control over A and B, I think you are in big trouble. You would need to find a specific version that is compatible with both A and B. If you do have control over A and B, I suggest updating B so that it depends on Ice 3.4.2 instead of 3.3.1.

Comment: It came out, that B owned dedicated version of ICE (with different namespace) and after I added new version of ICE it SOMEHOW clashed. I played a little bit with pom.xml file, changed order of dependencies and it solved my issue. Thanks anyway!